# Jquery onunload disconnect user

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to disconnect a user when "unload" event is fired !

```
$(window).bind('unload', function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "deconnexionUser.php",
      async: false
    });
});
```

It works but i don't want to use "async : false" !

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `beforeunload` you won't be competing with the window closing:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "deconnexionUser.php"
    });
});
```

Comment: Glad to help - if you can hit that tick button next to the answer it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

you cant start async events on the webpage being clossed, so you need to block the browser while you send the request.

is there a reason you want it to be async?

Comment: Yes i don't want to keep the user waiting !